# Particle properties blender Hair

Tags: modeling, animation, hair, error

My question is why does my model's hair look weird in bleders? What did I do wrong to make the dummy look like this?
I imported the model from Daz 3D .[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: We can't see your image. Could you try uploading it again? Thanks.